# Networkx : Make a graph more readable

Tags: python, graph, networkx, path-finding

Good afternoon.

I'm on a shortest path finder with A* project, and for that I took some osm data with osmnx.
When I want to plot my graph, I don't manage to print something good, even with changing the k parameter of spring_layout.
Also, I would like to print my nodes labels, and my edges labels without printing the tuple {"weight", label}.
I honestly didn't found how to make the whole thing clearer...

Do you have any idea ?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Data = open('edgelist_bruxelles.csv', "r")
    Graphtype = nx.MultiDiGraph()

    G = nx.parse_edgelist(Data, delimiter=',', create_using=Graphtype,
                          nodetype=int, data=(('weight', float),))
    
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, 10)
    
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=50)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, font_size=5)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='r', arrows=True)
    mp.show()
```

What I have  now

[image: 1]

Comment: GraphViz works great https://graphviz.org/

Comment: If this is a spatial graph, such as a street network, consider using OSMnx itself to [plot](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_graph) the graph to account for its complete spatial geometry (beyond just its topology). It can also plot paths along your graph. This will be much more legible, given that it's essentially a map.

Comment: Yes, in fact I used osmnx to generate my DB. But the need of a Conda environment makes impossible the use of osmnx in the resolution of the spf

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you could consider:

1. Add a title, perhaps some labels explaining what the nodes and vertices represent.
2. Determine what you want to show about the data. Currently, it is difficult to draw conclusions beyond 'many relationships'. If there is a particular path that you'd like to highlight, an approach could be to only display a smaller subset of the relationships or nodes.
3. You could also use color coding or something of the like to make things stand out more. For example, create a colormap for the different vertex values and see if anything stands out.
4. Removes nodes or order them deliberately to create less of a spiderweb.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try those few things. As I have to do a demo, I will probably choose a graph with less nodes to make it clearer